# Using IF statement along with AND, OR, or NOT in python

Tags: python, if-statement, statements

```
print "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!"

original = raw_input ("please, type a word") 

if len ('original') > 0 and original.isalpha():

    print original

else:

    print "empty"
```

What i'm trying to do is just make sure that the users input has more than 0 characters and make sure that are all letters, but when i write a number it prints the number, not "empty"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `original`, not `"original"`.

`"original"` is a literal string, while `original` is a variable name.

Over here:

```
len ('original')
     ^        ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean `len (original)` - otherwise it will always be true (you are calculating length of the string *"original"*.